# Ubuntu server behind corporate firewall

Tags: networking, apt, server, firewall

I really hope that someone here. I'm setting up an Ubuntu server behind a corporate firewall. I'm trying to get repositories to work. The problem I have found it that it is not that straight forward. For archive.ubuntu.com I have opened firewall ports 80 and 443, but then you also need port 11371 to keyserver.ubuntu.com. There are plenty more addresses and ports that needs to be opened to get everything to work properly.

So my main question is, is there a comprehensive list of all addresses and ports that need to be open in a cooperate firewall for apt to work?

Comment: You might find an answer here - [Another question on Ask Ubuntu for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/898562/ubuntu-sits-behind-a-corporate-proxy-firewall-how-can-i-install-packages) or [A question on StackOverflow for Ubuntu 12.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16988966/apt-get-not-working-behind-corporate-firewall-on-win-7-in-virtualbox-with-proxy)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately the links do not provide what I'm looking for. They only show how you connect through a proxy.

Comment: These days Ubuntu Server should be able to get updates on port 80 only.

Comment: Do you have to whitelist outgoing traffic from the server, or is there an internal proxy server in the company you can use?

Comment: To my knowledge we don't have a proxy so I'm forced to do whitelisting.

Answer (score 0):

Under /etc/apt/sources.list you can look up your sources and what port you are gonna need is something you have to check per source.

So, this may be outdated or datacenter specific. But I believe the following ports

86323
56421
12921
53
22

Another thing is if you are in a cooperate network are you sure you have all the right privileges to get this done?

Actually, in some cases, you are better of mirroring the repository server within the cooperation.

Comment: 86323 is not even a valid port number. Things these days is distributed over HTTP(S), which means 80 and 443. In addition you need working DNS, but that doesn't imply opening port 53 from the server towards the internet.

Answer (score 0):

> So my main question is, is there a comprehensive list of all addresses and ports that need to be open in a cooperate firewall for apt to work?

Plain and simple: No. There ain't. Because apt can be configured to use any repositories you want.

Even with the default, `tld.archive.ubuntu.com`, this is difficult. It redirects to other. Consider for instance `no.archive.ubuntu.com`:

```
$ dig no.archive.ubuntu.com +short
ubuntu-archive.trivini.no.
ftp.acc.umu.se.
194.71.11.173
194.71.11.165
```

These may very well change from time to time, so if you whitelist (based on DNS preferably) you will have to make sure your firewall solution updates it from time to time.

In addition to the local archive (probably `se.archive.ubuntu.com` in your case), you should add `security.ubuntu.com` to your whitelist. Both is accessible over port 80, normal HTTP.

For keys, you don't **need** open ports; you can fetch keys over http, and the number of keys is usually rather small, and you can add them manually. So I'd wager that you will manage with port 80 open towards `tld.archive.ubuntu.com` and `security.ubuntu.com`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have done precisely what you described. It is quite frustrating when one whitelists a domain and it's subdomains and all of the sudden they do a change. I will have to talk with the network team for an alternate solution.

Comment: You could have a look at where `se.archive.ubuntu.com` resolves, and use for instance `ftp.acc.umu.se` directly. This may be less volatile target.